# SQL Granting already existing rights to users / revoking them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to answer some questions based on the statements below. Initially, user A is the owner of relation R, and no other user holds privileges on R. The following are executed:

```
By A: GRANT INSERT ON R TO B WITH GRANT OPTION;
By B: GRANT INSERT ON R TO C WITH GRANT OPTION;
By C: GRANT INSERT ON R TO D WITH GRANT OPTION;
By D: GRANT INSERT ON R TO B WITH GRANT OPTION;
By B: REVOKE INSERT ON R FROM C CASCADE;
```

The questions are: What happens when D grants privileges to B, but they already exist? And what users still have the privileges after the last line is executed?

Comment: The latest changes in permissions always prevails. That means: whatever you did last is what is currently implemented / enforced. So, if `D` grants insert on R to B then this is what is currently enforced (if `D` has the permission to do so). If a `revoke` command is executed then all prior `grants` are being removed and `C` no longer has these permissions. Yet, note that you are only talking about `insert` permissions in the above example. `Select`, `delete`, or `update` permissions are not effected by any of these changes.

Comment: BTW, I did no down-vote your question. At the same time, I did notice in the past that people within the SQL community have a tendency to down-vote questions which seem trivial or banal to their standards. I guess they are used to much more difficult / complex questions and down-vote any post which is below par. After some years of SQL you might understand them. Yet, I fully support newcomers within the SQL community and support the urge of understanding the mysteries of SQL. So *(+1)* from my side and please don't stop asking questions.

Comment: @Ralph My downvote is for lack of research. The question is only good for the OP and no-one else, they didn't bother to dissect it and bring out the detail they don't understand (for that matter, didn't show a will to understand anything, only to get an answer for their specific homework).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that will help you to determine the answer for yourself.

```
-- setup
CREATE USER A WITHOUT LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE db_securityadmin ADD MEMBER A;
CREATE USER B WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER C WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER D WITHOUT LOGIN;

CREATE TABLE R (rid INT);

EXECUTE AS USER = 'A';
GRANT INSERT ON R TO B WITH GRANT OPTION;
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(grantee_principal_id), 
    user_name(grantor_principal_id), 
    permission_name, state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('dbo.R');

EXECUTE AS USER = 'B';
GRANT INSERT ON R TO C WITH GRANT OPTION;
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(grantee_principal_id), 
    user_name(grantor_principal_id), 
    permission_name, state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('dbo.R');

EXECUTE AS USER = 'C';
GRANT INSERT ON R TO D WITH GRANT OPTION;
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(grantee_principal_id), 
    user_name(grantor_principal_id), 
    permission_name, state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('dbo.R');

EXECUTE AS USER = 'D';
GRANT INSERT ON R TO B WITH GRANT OPTION;
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(grantee_principal_id), 
    user_name(grantor_principal_id), 
    permission_name, state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('dbo.R');

EXECUTE AS USER = 'B';
REVOKE INSERT ON R FROM C CASCADE;
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(grantee_principal_id), 
    user_name(grantor_principal_id), 
    permission_name, state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('dbo.R');

-- tear down
DROP TABLE R;
DROP USER D;
DROP USER C;
DROP USER B;
DROP USER A;
```

Don't run it all at once - run each grant and then examine what the permissions on `R` look like afterwards. As a plus, you now have the tools at your disposal to explore other scenarios!